# How to increase String variable value in C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a scenario where I have to increase the index by 1. Please check the below-

```
 String Index = "1.01"
```

I have a string variable "Index" and I have to increase it by 1 for next record in the table.

I tried to convert it into double first then adding 1 to it. But it seems it's not the good way to do that. Can anyone suggest a good way for it?

Comment: Could you explain why you're using a string to represent a number to start with? It sounds like it would be better if you could address that.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton, it's an existing code. I could not do anything with this.

Comment: You need to parse if you want to increment the value. please share your code to get suggestions for improvement

Comment: Sounds like you are doing the right thing tbh. Need to see the code to give you any more info

Comment: You may well want to parse it as a `decimal` rather than a `double` though, if you're representing a decimal value.

Comment: "But it seems it's not the good way to do that. " why do you think that?

Comment: Why it's not good idea to convert it to **Double**, than adding 1 to it, and than converting back to **String**?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = double.Parse(Index, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + 1;
```

That's normal, but keep numbers in string is not right.